# For $X_{n+1}=X_n+1/X_n$ with $ X_1=1 $, prove that $X_{100}>14$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, contest-math

Given the sequence:
$$X_{n+1}=X_n+1/X_n \qquad X_1=1, $$ prove that  $X_{100}>14$

Comment: proving it is increasing sequence, also calculating first 5 values, next  tried to express X100 with X1 getting some branch of continued fractions

Comment: Please use MathJax to write the equations.

Comment: i will try to use it as much as I can, I am new in tis community and still learning a lot, thanks for your edit and suggestion.

Comment: What is your work on this question ? Have you tried to compute the 100 first terms it on a computer in order to make conjectures ?

Comment: Hint:  consider $(x_n)^2$ and try to argue from that that $x_n≥\sqrt {2n-1}$.

Comment: Consider the solution given in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h407838p2278202 (where there is even a bracketing of the value of $x_n$) which amounts to work on auxiliary sequence $y_n:=x_n^2$ for which $y_{n+1}>y_n+2 \implies y_{100}>y_1+2 \times 99=199...$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Observe that $$x_{n+1}^2=x_n^2+2+\frac1{x_n^2}$$ Thus, you might notice that $$x_{n+2}^2=x_{n+1}^2+2+\frac1{x_{n+1}^2}=\left(x_{n}^2+2+\frac1{x_n^2}\right)+2+\frac1{x_{n+1}^2}>x_{n}^2+4$$ In fact, if you keep descending and use similar estimations, you will reach to the following conclusion $$x_{n+2}^2>x_1^2+2(n+1)=2n+3$$ You may use induction to prove this more rigorously. We are now done, since this yields $$x_{100}^2>2\cdot 98+3=199>196=14^2$$

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Sweet, I thought it was going to require continued fractions or some. Simple sequence bound proofs are beautiful. I had such a good grasp on this in Calc 2, but I think I've lost it. Do you know if there are books other than something like Stuart's Calculus textbook to learn about these kinds of problems?

Comment: @mathboy, If you click on the checkmark near the spot where you can upvote or downvote, then you will give the person who answered your question some amount of points. The points are actually useful as opposed to something like reddit - you can use your own to place "bounties" and make a question of your own get more attention.

Comment: @Algebraic, I fear I don't know any such book (in fact, I didn't even know the book you mentioned)...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, by induction you may prove that:
$$ (X_n)^2 \geq 2n-1 $$

**Base case** $n=1$:
$$1^2 \geq 2-1=1.$$
**(IH)** Then suppose  for some $k\in \mathbb N_{\geq 1}$ we have that:
$$ (X_k)^2 \geq 2k-1$$
We will now make the inductive step. Observe that by definition of the sequence we have:
$$ (X_{k+1})^2 =(X_k + 1/X_k)^2 =(X_k)^2 + 2 \frac{X_k}{X_k} + \frac{1}{(X_k)^2} \geq (X_k)^2 + 2 .$$
By the induction hypothesis we have:
$$ (X_{k+1})^2 \geq (X_k)^2 + 2 \geq (2k-1)+2 = 2(k+1)-1. $$
Then by the principle of mathematical induction the estimate holds for all $n \in $$\mathbb N_{\geq 1}$, in particular for $n=100$ we have that:
$$(X_{100})^2  \geq 200-1=199 > 196=14^2$$
Hence $X_{100}>14$.

Comment: thank you very much